# How to use JQuery .on() to catch the scroll event

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm attempting to use the .on() from jQuery to catch a scroll event that is inside a  tag.

so this was my solution:

- the div id='popup'
- the .fixedHeader class is something I'm trying have fixed at the top of the div frame.
- getScrollTop() is a javascript function to return the top value (works)

  ```
  $(document).on("scroll#popup", '#popup', function(){
     alert('scrolling');
     $(".fixedHeader").css("position", "relative");
     $(".fixedHeader").css("top", getScrollTop());
  });
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is simply `scroll`, not `scroll#popup`.

```
// http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter
// Also, be consistent with " vs '
var $fixedHeader = $('.fixedHeader').css('position', 'relative');

$(document).on('scroll', '#popup', function() {
   console.log('scrolling'); // you *really* don't want to alert in a scroll
   $fixedHeader.css("top", getScrollTop()); 
});
```

Comment: I've got a problem, the event doesn't seem to be picked up... and it doesn't write to the console. I'm trying to figure out if it might be because the <div> tag was dynamically generated.

Comment: I don't think that would cause the problem – that's part of what you get with using `.on()`.

Comment: then i don't know what is happening, the scroll event doesn't seem to be registering for the div tag, but it works for the window

Comment: Try `$(window).on('scroll', '#popup', function() { ...`

Comment: As @Venar303 says below,  $(document).on  does not work for the scroll event, you must bind it to the object that will throw the scroll event itself.

Answer (score 11):

The confusion is in how "on()" works. In jQuery when you say $(document).on(xx, "#popup", yy) you are trying to run yyy whenever the xx event reaches document but the original target was "#popup".

If document is not getting the xx event, then that means it isn't bubbling up! The details are in the jQuery On documentation, but the three events "load", "error" and "scroll" do not bubble up the DOM.

This means you need to attach the event directly to the element receiving it. 
$("#popup").on(xx,yy);

Answer (score 2):

As @Venar303 says, scroll doesn't bubble, thus binding to document will not work.

Use this:

```
$('#popup').on('scroll', function() {});
```

Instead of this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '#popup', function() {});
```