# Can't delegate scroll event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to fire an event on scroll on a particular class of elements, like so:

```
$('body').on('scroll', '.overflow', function() { do stuff; });
```

However, `do stuff` never happens. I've done a little experimentation, and it looks as though the scroll event can't be delegated using `.on`. (see http://jsbin.com/aJeDiru/2 for a test case).

Is there a way that I can get it to delegate? Or is there a Very Good Reason™ why it should never be set up to delegate in this fashion?

Comment: Well "scroll" is a weird event for bubbling, because it doesn't necessarily make sense for a parent element to get it if the child element scrolls independently.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625104/how-to-use-jquery-on-to-catch-the-scroll-event This should help (not the accepted answer though, the others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-scroll), the `scroll` event doesn't bubble.

Since event delegation relies on the event bubbling to the element you've attached the handler to, you won't be able to use delegation.

Answer (score 2):

Use "mousewheel" instead,
make sure #contents is on the main html file.

```
    $("#contents").on('mousewheel',function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
         //do something to the loaded elements
     } else {
        //do something to the loaded elements
     }
});
```