# Can't delegate a scroll event using "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I was trying to delegate a scroll event so that my element still has the same handler when it's returned by ajax call.
I use `on` to perform my delegation

```
$('body').on({
    scroll:function(){
        alert('scrolling');
    },
    click:function(){
        alert('clicked');
    }
},'.pt_pr_3_2');
```

the click event works, but the scroll doesn't.
[Here is the explanation why the scroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623958/cant-delegate-scroll-event-using-jquery?rq=1)

I wonder whether I have any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.pt_pr_3_2')
  .on('scroll', function(){
        alert('scrolling');
    })
  .on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

Comment: but it's not going to work when the element is returned from the ajax call, right?

Comment: @KesongXie Why not. Here you are using `on` so it will be valid for dynamically  created elements.