# What's the define difference between click and scroll events?

Tags: jquery

I have this lack of code:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="selected-log">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"></nav>
    <div style="overflow:auto; max-height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

When i define click like this all ok:

```
jQuery('#selected-log').on('click', 'div', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

But when i trying to get event on scroll like this nothing happens:

```
jQuery('#selected-log').on('scroll', 'div', function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

So is there some major difference between defining click and scroll?

Comment: @A.Wolff: You can... see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10625116/1719752

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Not sure what i was thinking, thx for the input

Comment: @MilindAnantwar But seems not to work and again after checking, SPEC says onscroll event doesn't bubble  UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/96EWU/  doesn't work

Comment: @A.Wolff: is it that way that it does not get bubble up for dom elements and work for document

Answer (score 0):

Your code for scroll using `.on()` does not work because scroll event does not bubble up the DOM tree:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html#t03

Comment: `jQuery('#selected-log').find('div').on('scroll', function()` work fine

Comment: Your code in the question is applying [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) not normal `.scroll()` method